# FragmentTransaction: set custom animations via code

Tags: java, android, fragmenttransaction

Is it possible to set custom animations for FragmentTransaction via code? I see only `setCustomAnimations(int, int)` that works for XML.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try this

```
FragmentTransaction transaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    //this is to add the animation
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.activity_open_enter,
            R.anim.activity_open_exit);

    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2);
    transaction.commit();
```

or you can read this
[Navigate between fragments using animations](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate)

hope can solve your problem :)